# "Only the time can/will tell" : a rare variant of "Only time can/will tell"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, language-evolution

In this video on the aftermath of the first launch of SpaceX Starship, at "[6m27s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKGiiDJ3Iq0&t=387s)" can be heard this apparently unusual sentence: "Only *the* time can tell."; personally, I've never heard or read this sentence with the use of the definite article before "time". Google ngram viewer confirms that this is very rare.

[image]

There is a related idiom sentence, "Only time *will* tell.", and dictionaries do not mention an alternative with "the".

[Cambridge  Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/only-time-will-tell)

[Collins  Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/time-will-tell)

[Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%28only%29%20time%20will%20tell)

[The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/only+time+will+tell)

[Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/only-time-will-tell#:%7E:text=From%20Longman%20Dictionary%20of%20Contemporary%20English%20%28only%29%20time,will%20tell%20%E2%80%A2%20BProbably%2C%20but%20time%20will%20tell.)

However, an ngram shows that there exists a budding usage.

[image]

It must be remarked that it is very recent—the occurrences are essentially confined to the last 15 years—, and that almost only Asian writers took to it, mostly from the Indian subcontinent or India. ([Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22only%20the%20time%20will%20tell%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en))

It seems to me that in the video the explanations that precede this sentence justify the usual form without "the", as the speaker does not make mention of a choice of specific times that would justify the use of the article, and then, even if that were the case, I wouldn't find this construction idiomatic.

Is this form to be considered as merely a departure from the standard form without "the" and possibly  to be only associated with fringe varieties of English such as Indian English, or perhaps an instance in a recent tendency towards change? Rather, is there a different meaning to be attached to it?

If the meaning to be reckoned with is that of the usual form, how acceptable is this new form (both idioms)?

Comment: The use of the definite article in “only the time will tell” are probably the result of literal translations from other languages. Seul le temps dira (French), solo il tempo dirà (Italian), el tiempo dirà (Spanish)

Comment: @user66974 I've added the page; I doubt that very many of these publications should come from Europe; they have to do with local concerns. Moreover, some authors are of Anglo-Saxon origin.

Comment: I think the writer of that video simply made a mistake.

Comment: That is merely a spoken English error as we all make in our lives. We don't say Anglo-Saxon in English to mean Anglo-American or English and American. It is silly to make a mountain out of the molehill of what is a  typical spoken mistake.

Comment: @Lambie  "Make a mountain out of a molehill" means "to exagerate the importance or the impact of something"; nowhere do I see in my words anything that can be evaluated as an exageration. I am trying only to make sure that there is not a new usage in the making.    Anyway, both comments and answers to this question are confined to the fact that this usage is an error. (1/2)

Comment: @Lambie  The SOED defines  "Anglo-Saxon" as "a person of English  (or British) descent wherever found". An Anglo-American" is defined as an American of English or British origin."Anglo-Saxon" includes all (Welsh, Scots, and all other of Anglo-Saxon stock: Americans, Canadians, Australians, New-Zealanders). It is not clear why "Anglo-Saxon" can't be used, nor that you find a restrictive term proper. (2/2)

Comment: You **deleted your comment with the term Anglo-Saxon** and now are citing to me the meaning?? English speakers are not referred to as Anglo-Saxon. It is the French and Spanish who use that to **mean** English speakers.

Comment: @Lambie None of my comments has been deleted by me and unless my memory is fuzzy all the comments I made are still on the page. // There are problems: first there is a dictionary definition that shows that "Anglo-Saxon" has come to mean much more than "English"; it's a definition from the Oxford English Dictionary.; second, all English speakers from the Indian subcontinent and from Africa are not from Anglo-Saxon origin, and they are therefore excluded when you use the term "Anglo-Saxon". It is obvious that I need to exclude those in my answer. "English speakers" won't do.

Comment: You had it there. Otherwise why would I even **mention it?** "Moreover, some authors are of Anglo-Saxon origin."

Comment: @Lambie That is rather strange: who would be the user I adressed that comment to? It makes no sense. "Some authors are of Anglo-Saxon origin.": that must be all (anyway, it is  proof enough that I used this term).

Answer (score 1):

Particularly in certain proverbial expressions, the word "time" refers to the *passage* of time; compare "Time heals all wounds." Since "time" thus refers to the passage of time *in general,* and not to any specific period of time, using "the time" here would make little semantic sense.

Comment: This answer could be one confirmation that no new meaning is involved and that time is understood to be time as a physical quantity. However, nothing is said about the article, which is the subject of an important part of the question. From comments already made I might begin to believe that one should not consider there is exist any general trend and that the case heard in the video is an error (which I have a hard time to believe).